# How to update the homepage in Joomla?

Tags: php, joomla

I have one website in Joomla, but I don't have any Joomla knowledge but I have to update the homepage. I have gone through all articles but I didn't find out any homepage related article.

Below is our website link,

http://www.usinpac.com/

And I have to remove "DIASPORA LEADERSHIP DIALOGUES" and "US Presidential Election 2016" which is in just above the Main-Menu bar (near search bar).

I got that particular images to remove, but I have to remove the both images (also attached below for your reference) with links and other stuffs.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How did you come by this task if you are not familiar with Joomla? If you are employed by the agency looking after this website, should they not be providing training on how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

These links are located in the header area of the template (rather than the main content) and are likely to be found in Module Manager. Log in to the back-end of the website and you should find these under Extensions -> Modules.

Comment: There links are located in the header area mean what will be the file name should be header.php like that or in some other file, because in Module Manager there is a big list that i saw so i am little bit confuse to find where is exactly located these links...

Comment: Yes, it's probably one or two of those items in the big list possibly using the "search" module position. If it's not obvious which modules to edit / disable then you probably need to get some professional help. There's only so much that can be done without seeing the list or logging in to the website.

Comment: Thank you so much @Neil, I got it in Template Manager Tab->Templates